# Azure ARM template deployment concat to construct CosmosDB connectionstring

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I tried to mimic the examples provided for constructing a storage account , but it throws "Unable to parse language expression. Expected token EndOfData and actual Right parenthesis" error

Here is the template
https://github.com/fashaikh/functions-aws-s3-cosmosdb-v1/blob/master/azuredeploy.json

```
"value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
```

works, but this doesnt:

```
"value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', reference(concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/', parameters('databaseAccountName'))).documentEndpoint, ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccountName')), '2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey)]"
```

The parenthesis seem to be balanced. I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#concat and couldnt figure out what I am missing or not seeing?

I deploy using deploy.azure.com 
https://deploy.azure.com/?repository=https://github.com/fashaikh/functions-aws-s3-cosmosdb-v1#/form/setup 
and the preview step of the template passes. Something is off about just the language expression

Comment: everything is fine with the piece of the template, error is elsewhere

Comment: also, you dont have to construct the url, because its always the same (i mean, predefined)

Comment: Here is what the error was earlier. It was the same line afaik 
![Screenshot ](https://i.imgur.com/7vmKcRc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I moved one fragment of the concat to the variables section and this worked
https://github.com/fashaikh/functions-aws-s3-cosmosdb-v1/blob/master/azuredeploy.json#L153

```
"value": "[concat('AccountName=', variables('accountEndpoint'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccountName')), '2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey)]"
```

Comment: this doesnt really differ from your original question. it works as is in your question, unless you can show a repro

Comment: Does the screenshot help? It shows the language expression in question here and has the error as well from deploy.azure.com 

![Screenshot ](i.imgur.com/7vmKcRc.png)